# Rent mobile WiFi hotspot for China

Tags: china, wifi

I will be traveling to Nanjing, China from Germany for 4 days and I would like to rent a mobile WiFi hotspot during my trip. Are there any recommended websites that offer it where I could pick up in the hotel or airport if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order a Huawei MIfI device for China and get a [China Unicom SIM card](https://www.mychinaunicom.com/) to use with it.

An alternative website I found is [this one](https://www.3gsolutions.com.cn) (no affiliation) which seems to offer the service.

Another website which offers this can be found [here](https://www.china-mobile-phones.com/china-mifi-hotspot-rental.html):

> With our China MiFi hotspot rental service, your laptop, apple devices, android phones, or tablets etc. can be connected to high-speed internet at the same time. While travelling in China, your family, friend or colleagues can share this 3G connection up to five Wi-Fi enabled devices.

(Prices can be found on that link)